# I want to write javascript code to get a addition countdown

Tags: javascript, loops

so basically this the prompt:

[Addition countdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oav02.png)

you enter a number and the code should be adding a number while countingdown, for example if the user enter 10, then the result should be:
`10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 +3 +2 +1=55`.

This is what I have so far:

```
var num = Number(prompt("Enter a Number Greater than zero"));

while (num > 0){

    first = num;

    second = num-=1;

    document.write(first +  " +" + second + " +");

    value = first + num;

    document.write(value)
    num--;
}
```

but I keep on getting something like this:
4 +3 +72 +1 +3 (*let's say 4 is the number the user inputs*)

I'm stuck can someone please help me????!!

Answer (score 2):

You could change the algorithm a bit, because for the first value, you need no plus sign for the output.

```js
var num = Number(prompt("Enter a Number Greater than zero")),
    value = 0;

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(num));
value += num;
num--;
while (num > 0) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' + ' + num));
    value += num;
    num--;
}
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' = ' + value));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep total in one variable outside of `while` loop.

```js
var num = Number(prompt("Enter a Number Greater than zero"));

var total = 0;
while (num > 0) {
  total += num;
  document.body.innerHTML += (num == 1 ? num + ' = ' + total : num + ' + ');
  num--;
}
```

Comment: @Nina Scholz I displayed total before incrementing it.